# Add individual distinct points to an existing matplotlib plot in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a plot produced by matplotlib which shows trajectories of stochastic equations. I wish to add a seperate set of points inside this existing plot. Is it possible to do so?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

There are many approaches, but the two most common ones are `patches.Circle()` and `ax.scatter()`. The only difference between them is that `ax.scatter` has color map support.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,4.5),dpi=144)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

xx = np.random.randint(5,95,(100,))
yy = np.random.randint(75,85,(100,))
ss = np.random.randint(1,5,(100,))
color = ['r','b','g','y','m']

for i,(x,y,s) in enumerate(zip(xx,yy,ss)):
    c = patches.Circle(xy=(x, y), radius=s, fc=color[s-1], alpha=0.4)
    ax.add_patch(c)

for i,(x,y,s) in enumerate(zip(xx,yy,ss)):
    ax.scatter(xx, yy-25, s=s*20, c=yy, cmap='Blues', marker='o', alpha=0.7)

for i,(x,y,s) in enumerate(zip(xx,yy,ss)):
    ax.scatter(xx, yy-50, s=50, c='pink', edgecolor='r', marker='o', alpha=0.9)

ax.set_ylim(0,100)
ax.set_xlim(0,100)
ax.set_aspect('equal')

plt.show()
```

[image]